# AngularJS $broadcast and $emit in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, angularjs

I have seen a few tutorials about $broadcasting in angularjs, and I know the angular(2+) isn't the same thing, so I want to ask if $broadcast and $emit are included in angular(2+) or $broadcast and $emit functionalities are achievable using @input and @output?

Comment: In angular 2+, you could use subjects and behaviour subjects to achieve broadcast and emit functiinality. Input and @output only works for parent child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In angular 2+, you could use subjects and behaviour subjects to achieve broadcast and emit functionality. @Input and @output only works for parent child